# Выбор из списка значений по регулярному выражению

Tags: python, python-3.x, регулярные-выражения, list

Есть список в Python `a = ['data1', 'asdf', 'data2', 'fghh', 'jhgf', 'data3']`как одним выражением получить из него другой список, который будет содержать всё элементы первого, начинающиеся с 'data'? Как получить список всех элементов списка а, содержащих в названии числа?

Comment: ЯП какой? Или Вам на псевдокоде подойдёт?

Comment: @XelaNimed видимо python, раз список

Comment: Поставьте метку ЯП. @Павел тут может быть и неправильная трактовка/формулировка, но в любом случае необходима метка.

Comment: Спасибо, добавил что это Python

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Через регулярные выражения можно реализовать следующим образом:

> Как одним выражением получить из него другой список, который будет
> содержать всё элементы первого, начинающиеся с 'data'

```
import re

a = ['data1', 'asdf', 'data2', 'fghh', 'jhgf', 'data3']

b = [x for x in a if re.match(r'data.*', x)]

print(b) # ['data1', 'data2', 'data3']
```

> Как получить список всех элементов списка а, содержащих в названии
> числа?

```
a = ['data1', 'asdf', 'data2', 'fghh', 'jhgf', 'data3', 'some1']

b = [x for x in a if re.match(r'.*\d.*', x)]

print(b) # ['data1', 'data2', 'data3', 'some1']
```

**Дополнительно**

Я считаю, что более удобно реализовать эту фильтрацию будет через `list comprehenshion`, для данных задач он чуть более удобно применяется за счет встроенных в Python функций `startswith()` и `isdigit()`. Вот как можно реализовать тот же самый функционал:

Поиск элементов, начинающихся с `data`:

```
b = [x for x in a if x.startswith('data')]
```

Поиск элементов, содержащих цифры:

```
b = [x for x in a if any(map(str.isdigit, x))]
```